# How to fix 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'X''

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

I'm currently setting up a website page ('records' page) that counts the amount of total people that went on another website page ('site' page), so I set up a cookie on the site page that increments said data in a database.

I've seen other users get this problem because they included a "AND" statement in their "SET" statement. I however don't have an "AND" statement

In my repository, I have this code:

```
public function addConnections($name): int
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('connectionCounter')
        ->update('App\Entity\site', 'connectionCounter')
        ->set('connectionCounter.nbConnections', 'connectionCounter.nbConnections + 1')
        ->where('connectionCounter.name = (:name)')
        ->setParameter('name', $name)
        ->getQuery();

    return $qb->execute();
}
```

and in my controller, I have this code:

```
if($repository)
{
    $query = $this->getDoctrine()
                  ->getRepository(Activity::class)
                  ->findActivities($repository[0]->getIdSite());

    $cookieCreator = 0;
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['Connection'])) {
        setcookie("Connection","1",time()+60*60*24*100);

        $connections = $this->getDoctrine()
                            ->getRepository(Site::class)
                            ->addConnections($repository[0]->getIdSite());
}
```

What I expect is my database getting updated, and when I go on the records page, I see that the amount of visits incremented.

What actually happens is this:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE site SET nb_connections = nb_connections + 1 WHERE name = (?)' with params [2]:

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'X '
```

Even an explanation as to why this could happen would be great!

Comment: What's your table schema? It should like `nb_connections` is a date time, so you can't just add 1 to it.

Comment: Don't worry, I just found the solution. In my controller, I have getIdSite, when I should have getName. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight oversight on my part, in my controller, I have:

```
->addConnections($repository[0]->getIdSite());
```

When it should be:

```
->addConnections($repository[0]->getName());
```

I changed it, it works now. Sorry!